# Search not working and fetch wrong results in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

the Search doesn't work and retrieves wrong results

That worked with me if I searched with username only but when I made that search with username, customer and dates the results not become incorrectly

My Model

```
public function search_count($username,$customer,$datefrom,$dateend) {
    $this->db->where('t_u_id',$username);
    $this->db->where('t_customer_id',$customer);
    $this->db->where('t_date <=',$dateend);
    $this->db->where('t_date >=',$datefrom);
    return $this->db->count_all("transactions");
}
public function search($username,$customer,$datefrom,$dateend,$limit,$start)
{
    $start=$start-1;
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('transactions');
    $this->db->where('t_u_id',$username);
    $this->db->where('t_customer_id',$customer);
    $this->db->where('t_date <=',$dateend);
    $this->db->where('t_date >=',$datefrom);
    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
    public function search($page_num = 1){
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->model(array('CustomReport_m','user','Customer_m')); // This array to save number of lines only
    $username=$this->input->post('select_user');
    $username = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $username;
    $customer=$this->input->post('select_customer');
    $customer = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : $customer;
    $datefrom=$this->input->post('from');
    $datefrom = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : $datefrom;
    $dateend=$this->input->post('to');
    $dateend = ($this->uri->segment(6)) ? $this->uri->segment(6) : $dateend;
    $total_row = $this->CustomReport_m->search_count($username,$customer,$datefrom,$dateend);
    //$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['base_url'] = site_url("CustomReport/search/$username/$customer/$datefrom/$dateend");
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    if ($this->uri->segment(7)) {
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(7));
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }
    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"]= explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
    $data['users']=$this->user->display_users();
    $data['userdata'] = $this->user->userdata();
    $data['customers']= $this->Customer_m->index();
   if(isset($username)and !empty($username)){
       $data["rsl"] =$this->CustomReport_m->search($username,$customer,$datefrom,$dateend,$config["per_page"],$page);
        $this->load->view('customreport_v',$data);
    }else{
        redirect('CustomReport','refresh');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
    public function search_count($username,$customer,$datefrom,$dateend) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('transactions');
        $this->db->where('t_u_id', $username);
        $this->db->where('t_customer_id', $customer);
        $this->db->where('t_date <=', $dateend);
        $this->db->where('t_date >=', $datefrom);
        return $this->db->get()->num_rows();
    }
```

Because count_all function just returns total of rows, it cannot apply where.

Comment: Updated but nothing changed!

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong function. If you mean search function doesn't work, you should look at your if else condition at the end of your controller, you should write if(isset($username)) or if(!empty($username)), your condition is not working because AND keyword doesn't exist, if you want to use AND, you must use &&.

Comment: Updated and when the result one row I can't see anything and if that 2 rows that appear well

Comment: I think it depends on your start number.

Comment: I think that also

Comment: But I don't think that use too much info get from url is a good idea. You just need a form, then you send data from the form with method post, and you need one uri_segment to get page_num.

Comment: Yeah, i made that, but that the URI_SEGMENT works when the result more than 10 rows, I just need to view the results if the results 1 row only!